# Wi-Fi issues in Kubuntu on MacBook Pro - Wi-Fi interface not detected

Tags: networking, kubuntu, broadcom, macbook

I installed Kubuntu on my MacBook Pro, but I'm having trouble with my Wi-Fi connection. The network interface is not being detected, and I'm unable to connect to any Wi-Fi networks. I have checked the output of 'lspci -nnk' and confirmed that the Broadcom BCM4364 wireless network adapter is recognized, and the 'wl' module is loaded. However, the Wi-Fi interface does not appear in the output of 'ip link show'. I have already tried restarting the Network Manager service and updating the system, but the issue persists. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this problem and get my Wi-Fi working on my MacBook Pro running Kubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)